# Improve Jspdf quality

Tags: jspdf

when we use addHTML(), generated  pdf quality is poor.

To improve quality, I write this code.

```
            var pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'in', 'a4');
            pdf.internal.scaleFactor = 30;
            pdf.addHTML($('#print-area')[0], function () {
                pdf.save(calendarName);
            });
```

This may help someone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when we use addHTML(), generated pdf quality is poor.

To improve quality, I write this code.

```
        var pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'in', 'a4');
        pdf.internal.scaleFactor = 30;
        pdf.addHTML($('#print-area')[0], function () {
            pdf.save(calendarName);
        });
```

This may help someone

Comment: This is supposed to help how? Applying your solution things appear with ant size on the pdf.

Comment: for me this solution work. And thing also readable